# Trying to make an array of my static classes

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, static

I have a class that prints a pattern

```
public static void Pattern1()
{
    for (i = rowQuantity; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print( rowQuantity-j );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I have several different patterns similar to this one, and what I want to do (if possible) is create a static class that prints an array where each element is one of these patterns. Can I do this? I want to be able to print the patterns side by side.

I tried something like this to no avail:

```
public static void display()
{
    rowQuantity = 5;
    TriangleDiamondPrinter[] pattern = new TriangleDiamondPrinter[4];
    pattern[0] = Pattern1();
    pattern[1] = Pattern2();
    pattern[2] = Pattern3();
    pattern[3] = Pattern4();

    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
        //System.out.print( (i+1) + ")  " + pattern[i] + "    ");
}
```

The (i+1) part is just to label each array by it's pattern # and the empty spaces are just to create some space between the patterns.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What you have are methods and they are by themselves no objects that you can put in an array.

Comment: There is no such thing as a stand-alone "static class" in Java. You've got static methods -- and that's a big difference. The little details matter here.

Comment: Thanks zapl I am pretty new to this and am confused with all the terminology.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure you can. Note that when you say

```
pattern[i]
```

you're simply referring to the object itself stored at index i inside the pattern array. If you want the pattern to actually print, you have to do something like

```
pattern[i].printPattern()
```

in this case above you're actually calling a method belonging to the object through its class structure.

Note that what you have above isn't a class.

```
public static void Pattern1()
```

This is declaring a method/function. You want to put that inside something like

```
public class FirstPattern {...}
```

If you really want a bunch of different classes like FirstPattern, SecondPattern, etc. I suggest you have all of them extend a common Pattern class which holds a printPattern(). A simple example is below:

```
public class Pattern {
    public void printPattern() {
      System.out.println("This should not print");
    }
}
```

And now...

```
public class FirstPattern extends Pattern {
    @override
    public void printPattern() {
      //print your pattern stuff here...
    }
}
```

Thus, your FirstPattern, SecondPattern, etc. classes can all override the printPattern() method with their own unique pattern. This way, you can make your array hold objects of type Pattern.

```
Pattern[] array = new Pattern[...];
```

Now, you can iterate through the array, and since all of them extend Pattern, you can call printPattern for each FirstPattern, SecondPattern, etc. object and the patterns will print. Note that the Pattern keyword before the [] is basically saying "this array will hold objects that are Patterns" - by having all of your subclasses (FirstPattern, etc.) extend the Pattern superclass, a FirstPattern object is a Pattern, a SecondPattern object is also a Pattern, and so forth. So, although FirstPattern is different from SecondPattern, inheritance lets you store these two "different" types in the same array. I believe you're trying to implement a simple form a polymorphism, which basically means you have a set of objects that can behave differently when a single method is called from each of them. Note that an interface can also get the job done.

Comment: Don't delete the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092484/why-is-ruby-filling-up-the-entire-2d-array) to ignore other efforts.. You got help doesn't mean, all future reader got it.

Comment: Only one down vote, you got. Who knows in future you wouldn't get more votes on it.

Answer (score 2):

`Pattern1` is not a "static class" - it's a static method. Also, you can't do `pattern[0] = Pattern1();` because `Pattern1` returns `void`

From what I understand, you want to have an array with different patterns, and loop though that array while printing them all. To do that you need to use polymorphism. First, you create an interface:

```
public interface IPattern{
    public String getPatternString();
}
```

Then you implement that interface:

```
public class Pattern1 implements IPattern{
    public String getPatternString(){
        //code to build a string and return it
    }
}
```

And so on for `Pattern2` etc. Finally, you fill an array with those patterns, and iterate over it each time calling `getPatternString` on the next entry:

```
public static void display()
{
    IPattern[] pattern = new IPattern[4];
    pattern[0] = new Pattern1();
    pattern[1] = new Pattern2();
    pattern[2] = new Pattern3();
    pattern[3] = new Pattern4();

    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
        System.out.print( (i+1) + ")  " + pattern[i].getPatternString() + "    ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a stand-alone "static class" in Java. You've got static methods -- and that's a big difference. The little details matter here.

If you want a type that has a public method that behaves differently in different concrete class implementations, consider creating an interface, say called MyPattern, giving it a method, say `public void printPattern();` (note method should begin with a lower-case letter), and then create a collection of these, an `ArrayList<MyPattern>`. Then you could iterate through the list calling `printPattern()` on each object in the collection.